# Blocking call caught by BlockHound on reactive MongoDB using Webflux and Kotlin

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, blockhound

I implemented a simple CRUD using Spring Webflux, Spring data Coroutine Repository and reactive mongodb, but when I used BlockHound I got an error from a blocking call on the mongo session creation.
Here is the log:

```
    reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call! java.io.FileInputStream#readBytes
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler br.com.promocerva.sales.controller.SaleController#create(SaleDTO, Continuation) [DispatcherHandler]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/api/sales" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:279) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.readFully(NativePRNG.java:424) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.ensureBufferValid(NativePRNG.java:526) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:545) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:220) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:741) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.UUID.randomUUID(UUID.java:150) ~[na:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.session.ServerSessionPool$ServerSessionItemFactory.createNewServerSessionIdentifier(ServerSessionPool.java:267) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.session.ServerSessionPool$ServerSessionItemFactory.create(ServerSessionPool.java:248) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.session.ServerSessionPool$ServerSessionItemFactory.create(ServerSessionPool.java:245) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ConcurrentPool.createNewAndReleasePermitIfFailure(ConcurrentPool.java:231) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ConcurrentPool.get(ConcurrentPool.java:169) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ConcurrentPool.get(ConcurrentPool.java:147) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.session.ServerSessionPool.get(ServerSessionPool.java:86) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.session.BaseClientSessionImpl.<init>(BaseClientSessionImpl.java:49) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.ClientSessionPublisherImpl.<init>(ClientSessionPublisherImpl.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-reactivestreams-4.4.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.ClientSessionHelper.createClientSession(ClientSessionHelper.java:90) ~[mongodb-driver-reactivestreams-4.4.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.ClientSessionHelper.lambda$createClientSessionMono$1(ClientSessionHelper.java:60) ~[mongodb-driver-reactivestreams-4.4.2.jar:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.subscribe(MonoCallable.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.OperationExecutorImpl.lambda$execute$13(OperationExecutorImpl.java:130) ~[mongodb-driver-reactivestreams-4.4.2.jar:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFromPublisher.subscribe(MonoFromPublisher.java:63) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:195) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.subscribe(MonoSupplier.java:62) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onError(FluxFilter.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:259) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:238) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:238) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoUsingWhen.subscribe(MonoUsingWhen.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.AwaitKt.awaitOne(Await.kt:190) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-reactive-1.5.2.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.AwaitKt.awaitOne$default(Await.kt:183) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-reactive-1.5.2.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.AwaitKt.awaitSingleOrNull(Await.kt:141) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-reactive-1.5.2.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvokeReactiveToSuspended(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:185) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:98) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at br.com.promocerva.sales.controller.SaleController.create$suspendImpl(SaleController.kt:30) ~[main/:na]
        at br.com.promocerva.sales.controller.SaleController.create(SaleController.kt) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.6.10.jar:1.6.10-release-923(1.6.10)]
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Instance.call(CallerImpl.kt:113) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.6.10.jar:1.6.10-release-923(1.6.10)]
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.call(KCallableImpl.kt:108) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.6.10.jar:1.6.10-release-923(1.6.10)]
        at kotlin.reflect.full.KCallables.callSuspend(KCallables.kt:56) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.6.10.jar:1.6.10-release-923(1.6.10)]
        at org.springframework.core.CoroutinesUtils.lambda$invokeSuspendingFunction$2(CoroutinesUtils.java:79) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at kotlin.coroutines.intrinsics.IntrinsicsKt__IntrinsicsJvmKt$createCoroutineUnintercepted$$inlined$createCoroutineFromSuspendFunction$IntrinsicsKt__IntrinsicsJvmKt$4.invokeSuspend(IntrinsicsJvm.kt:205) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar:1.6.10-release-923(1.6.10)]
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar:1.6.10-release-923(1.6.10)]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:367) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.2.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.2.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.2.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.2.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.2.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.reactor.MonoKt.monoInternal$lambda-2(Mono.kt:90) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-reactor-1.5.2.jar:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:292) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:336) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:101) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:159) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.16.jar:3.4.16]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:400) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:419) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:600) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:93) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:266) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.17.jar:1.0.17]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327) ~[netty-codec-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299) ~[netty-codec-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:800) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

The controller method:

```
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    suspend fun create(@RequestBody sale: SaleDTO): SaleDTO {
        return saleRepository.save(sale.toEntity()).let {
            it.toDto()
        }
    }
```

The repository is extending CoroutineCrudRepository:

```
interface SaleRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<Sale, String> {

}
```

Here is the build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.6"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.10"
}

group = "br.com.promocerva"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2021.0.1"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(module = "mockito-core")
    }
    implementation("io.projectreactor.tools:blockhound:1.0.6.RELEASE")
    testImplementation("com.ninja-squad:springmockk:3.0.1")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-debug")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I also added some BlockHound integrations but the error persists:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    BlockHound.install(
        ReactorBlockHoundIntegration(),
        ReactiveAdapterRegistry.SpringCoreBlockHoundIntegration()
    )
    runApplication<SalesApplication>(*args)
}
```

I have little experience with nonblocking code, I could add the blocking method to BlockHound allowed methods but I am not sure if this is the right thing to do, and I don't know how to solve this issue as it seems to be related to reactive mongo driver.

Answer (score 0):

Issue comes from netty concurrent method with fast access to FastThreadLocal variables. You need to allow blocking method.

```
public class BlockHoundCustomConfiguration implements BlockHoundIntegration {

        @Override
        public void applyTo(BlockHound.Builder builder) {
            builder.allowBlockingCallsInside("io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable", "run");
        }
    }
```

Check BlockHound customizations:
https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound/blob/master/docs/customization.md#dis-allowing-blocking-calls-inside-methods